# Changing the textview text with my randomized string array(Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Trying to put the array into the textview each time this page is called

Each time I tried to go to this page to have it put the random string it errors at `txt1.Text = ans;` this line saying "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
namespace App4
{
    [Activity(Label = "Winner")]
    public class Winner : Activity
    {

        TextView txt1;
        Button btn1;

        String[] array_of_strings =
            {
        "Congratulations!",
        "Did you get lucky? either way grats!",
        "Roses are red, violets are blue. Congrats! I am oh-so happy for you!",
        "Funny how easy this game is aint i right",
        "Wow so you have attention span greater than a goldFish",
            };



        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout2);


            randomCongratulations();
            txt1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Txt1);
            btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1);

            btn1.Click += (o, e) =>
            {
                Intent NextPage = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(NextPage);
            };
        }
        public void randomCongratulations()
        {
            String ans = array_of_strings[new Random().Next(array_of_strings.Length)];
            txt1.Text = ans;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to initialize the view before using it(here is `txt1`).

So you try to move code `randomCongratulations();` after the following code:

```
 txt1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Txt1);
```

So the adjusted code looks like this:

```
        txt1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Txt1);
        btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1);

        randomCongratulations();

        btn1.Click += (o, e) =>
        {

        };
```